# Why does binding a collection to a datagrid result in a different collectionview?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Suppose I have this:

```
public IList<TestObj> collection { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        collection = new ObservableCollection<TestObj>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

 <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

  </DataGrid>
```

Fairly standard WPF stuff. But here's something that suprised me when checking the immediate window: (grid.Items implements ICollectionView)

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection) == grid.Items
false
```

but of course...

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection) == CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(grid.Items.SourceCollection)
true
```

That mysterious static method of retrieving the collectionview from an object has surprised me, I figured it would do this: Retrieve the collection view of which a bound object will look at, but it appears two different implementees of the ICollectionview interface can coexist

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> grid.Items implements ICollectionView

That's because `ItemsControl.Items` *always* implements `ICollectionView`. It's always an instance of `ItemCollection`, which inherits `CollectionView`, which of course implements `ICollectionView`.

In other words, the default collection for `ItemsControl` itself implements `ICollectionView`. But this is not in any way required to be the actual view used by the control. And in fact, if you bind a different collection to `ItemsSource`, it stands to reason that you will get a different implementation for `ICollectionView` for that different collection. After all, `ItemCollection` implements `ICollectionView` for itself, not for any other collection. And the `ItemsSource` collection is "any other collection".

Or to look at it another way, the `ICollectionView` returned by `ItemsControl.Items` is the view for the `Items` collection itself (it just happens the collection is its own view). On the other hand, the `ICollectionView` returned by `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection)` is the view for `collection`, which is necessarily different from the view for `Items`.